# How do I know which files in a directory arn't in my SVN repository?

Tags: svn

The tile is exactly my question.

[edited out mistaken code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) command.

If you didn't set ignore property the files will be shown with '?' prefix.

Comment: If you want to filter out files with other statuses, you can use something like svn status|grep -e '^\?'
This will work better if there are only a few unadded files in a large directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a PC, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) highlights each file with an overlay icon indicating its status with respect to SVN

Answer (score 2):

From command line if you run "svn st" files not under subversion control will show with a ? beside them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `svn stat` to see any files that exist in your working copy that aren't being ignored and are not in your repository. They will be marked with a question mark ?. To see every file that is not in the repository (even those that would normally be ignored by svn), use svn stat --no-ignore.

Answer (score 2):

To amplify @RichardE's answer, the icons in Tortoise SVN look like:

[alt text http://img144.imageshack.us/img144/1906/subversionicons.png](http://img144.imageshack.us/img144/1906/subversionicons.png)

The files that aren't yet in the repository are marked with a "?"

(From the Help file).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on linux, from the topmost directory which you have under svn, run this command:

```
svn status
```

Any files that come up as having the ? symbol beside them are not under version control.  You can add them with 'svn add < filename >'

Commit them to your repository as usual with svn commit.