# How to create SVN for codeigniter

Tags: php, svn, codeigniter, installation

I would like to learn using projects in SVN. Thats why I would like to create Codeigniter  project installation with SVN.

How can I do that?

Comment: Google 'setup SVN' then add your codeigniter installation to the repository

Comment: There's nothing special about CodeIgniter + SVN... Where are you stuck?

Comment: @deceze: I've never used SVN before. I was hoping that there are step-by-step instructions how to setup this... I guess I should read a book about SVN first..

Comment: I recommend http://svnbook.red-bean.com.

Comment: @deceze: Thank you, I will read that book :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn how to use SVN. Once you know how to use that, or any other version control system, setting up a CodeIgniter project in a repo is very straightforward.

Here are some resources on where to learn SVN: [How do I learn to use SVN effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774677/how-do-i-learn-to-use-svn-effectively)